# How to work at NASA

Tags: nasa

I guess it might seems like a spam or a troll one, but actually I'm serious. I'm firt year Mechanical engineer (3 and half to go) and I'd love to work there, Since I was young kid I found that space and space exploration are very intersting thing.

Sorry about my spelling mistakes, My origin is not from th US

Comment: Probably the most important step you can take is [apply for a job](http://nasajobs.nasa.gov/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about space exploration.

Comment: Speaking as someone who worked on and off at NASA/GSFC for 25 years, your best bet is to find a contractor working in the area of your specialty rather than trying for a direct NASA government job, as there are usually far more of these than direct NASA spots. The top 100 NASA contractors list (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NASA_contractors) is probably a good starting point. If you want to go the direct route, try http://nasajobs.nasa.gov for a list of open positions.

Comment: [Other than under extremely rare exceptions, you must be a U.S. citizen in order to work for NASA as a civil service employee.](http://nasajobs.nasa.gov/jobs/noncitizens.htm) The same applies to most NASA contractors.